# vim: count characters in a buffer from a function

Tags: vim

in vim, with `strlen`, I can count the number of characters in a line.

Example: count the characters in last line

```
 strlen(getline('$'))
```

how I can count the characters in the buffer ?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/25923/10254

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `g CTRL-G` to display stats of the current buffer, including char count.

`line2byte(line('$') + 1)` works in scripts.

Comment: but, how I use this in a vim function ?

Comment: Note: According to the help for line2byte. `line2byte(line('$') + 1)` is the file size `+1`