# How to get character count using vi or Vim

Tags: vim, count, character, vi

How do you get character location count from a text file using vi?

I tried ":goto number" and it does not work in Linux.

To clarify my question, if I have a file with, say, three lines:

```
I am going for a walk
because today is a
beautiful day.
```

I want to, say, find a letter in position 30, and it will jump to line 2, highlighting letter 't' from word 'today'. This is similar to concept of `:goto 30` in macOS vi, but for Linux.

Comment: `:%s/.//gn<cr>` is one way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vim: count characters in a buffer from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262902/vim-count-characters-in-a-buffer-from-a-function)

Comment: `:h wordcount()`

Comment: I updated my question to clarify what I mean. The question is not a duplicate for what phd is referencing. Thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 42):

**Answer updated for 2023 to include byte / character differentiation in latest VIM release**

Use <kbd>g</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>

The output looks like

`Col 1 of 5; Line 1 of 31; Word 1 of 48; Char 1 of 570; Byte 1 of 571`

`Col 1 of 5;` refers to the position of the cursor on the `line` you are on

`Line 1 of 31;` refers to the line your cursor is currently on

`Char 1 of 570` refers to the character you are on: (char 1) vs the **total** characters in the file (570)

`Byte 1 of 571` refers to the **byte** you are on: (byte 1) vs the **total** bytes in the file (571).  Since bytes and characters are not the same thing, being that some characters are Unicode Multibyte Characters, this number *may* differ from character count.

This should be what you need to **get** to that character:

`:go30`

Here is what it looks like on command line:

[image: :go30]

Comment: Your answer is interesting but not quiet what I was looking for. I updated my question to clarify further. Thanks!

Comment: What about `:go30`

Comment: do a `sudo apt-get install vim` to get the latest `vim` with all the available commands

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with `vim` Version 7.4.1689  --  do a `vi -v` to look at your `vim` version.

Comment: Since characters and bytes are not the same thing: e.g., if there are unicode multibyte characters, it would be nice to know how to do it for actual characters.

Comment: Running this command now returns `"Col 1 of 37; Line 1 of 586; Word 1 of 3557; Char 1 of 25042; Byte 1 of 25047"`, which addresses the unicode character issue :) @frabjous

Comment: According to the current documentation (and my experience) it has to be `g`, `Ctrl` + `G`. First `g` has to be lower case. https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#g_CTRL-G

Comment: @Moritz -- 5 years and nobody brought up my typo!   Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Count characters in just part of a file (or all of file if you need).
First visualise the area you want to count.

1. visualize a paragraph with <kbd>v}</kbd>
2. visualize the whole file with <kbd>ggVG</kbd>

Then type

```
:%s/\%V./&/g
```

I needed this to count my Twitter posts (280 character limit).

Comment: What is the explanation of the command that you suggested?

Comment: \%V  represents the visualised text, then replace every character '.' with itself '&' . This leaves text exactly the same but counts how many characters 'replaced'

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. It looks like I had 'vi' and 'vim' installed on my system. By default, I was using 'vi' to edit the file and `:goto 30` did not work. After a bit of digging around I found that 'vi' was part of the `vim-minimal` package. And 'vim' was part of the `vim-enhanced` package. When I tried 'vim' instead of 'vi' the `:goto 30` worked! So it looks like it is definitely package related. Thanks Zak, pointing in the right direction and to all for the help.

Comment: Technically my answer worked, --  Including the fact that I asked you to check your `VIM` version.and install the updated package if needs be --  Anyone who read my answer would have arrived at 1) `:goto 30` works .. And 2) if it didn't, check your `vim` version.   Answering your own question was unnecessary.